# Why is it giving an error node expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, unexpected-token

There is a problem when i run this code by nodemon it gives me the following error

```
app.post('/register',async (req,res)=>{
try {
    const hashedPassword =await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10);
    users.push({
        id: Date.now().toString(),
        name: req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:hashedPassword

    });
    res.redirect('/login')
    }
catch {

      res.redirect('/register')
      }

console.log(users)
`});``
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: /home/hp/projects/L/login/server.js:28
catch {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax for try ... catch is as follows

```
try {
   //do something
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Also you have a bunch of ` at the end, but I think that is just formatting issues in your question. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) is a reference.